# Icon of the menu item not appearing

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, menu

I hope to find answer of this question and any help will be appreciated,
when i use `blank\empty activity` the icon of the `menu` item doesn't appear !
but using `basic activity` it works fine .
thanks in advance .
this is the menu `xml`code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/one"
    android:icon="@drawable/images"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="one"
    />
```

its works as i said for `basic` Activity but its not for `empty\blank` Activity 
for the appearance of the `menu icon`

Comment: please try uploading your code to get some edits and explain what you've tried already.

Comment: ok , i will edit the post .

Comment: would you like to see the edited post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` put this in menu before your  item tag and use 'app:' instead of 'android:' at "showAsAction"  LIKE
  use this:

```
 app:showAsAction="always"
```

instead of

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: Its work now . Thank you man but can you explain why we changed " android " into " app"

Comment: Because showAsAction is not in android directory .It is in app directory.you can accept my answer so others can get help.